# Iphone add to home screen issue

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have added this http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen plugin to a website and it works ok but I have a question. For a better understanding I will describe the scenario.

SCENARIO:
The user enters the site and the add to home screen pop-up appears, he taps the add to home screen icon and adds it to his iPhone homescreen.So far so good. He enters the site from the homescreen icon and whenever he taps a link it will open in a SAFARI window not in the current window. The desired beahviour would be to let the user in the current fullscreen window not to redirect him to a regular safari window. NONE of the links have target _blank. Is this an iPhone bug or is it a "normal" behaviour ?

Comment: Yes that is expected behaviour

Comment: Can you please give me a link where I can read more about it?

Comment: Yes, search SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=home+screen+iphone+same+window